# PHP how to aggregate 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, excel, aggregate-functions

I have a 2D array in PHP, I need to aggregate the data inside it before saving it into an EXCEL sheet with PHPExcel. My data is already sorted by country. Each sub-array has a country name. what I want to do is to add a total number of the field "LIVE" per country. My table looks like this:

```
[
    [314] => Array
            (
                [Country] => France
                [provider] => HIberica
                [status] => inactive
                [# per status] => 1
                [Live] => 0
            )

        [315] => Array
            (
                [Country] => France
                [provider] => HIberica
                [status] => active
                [# per status] => 4223
                [Live] => 4171
            )

        [316] => Array
            (
                [Country] => United States
                [provider] => HarperC
                [status] => pending
                [# per status] => 69
                [Live] => 0
            )

        [317] => Array
            (
                [Country] => United States
                [provider] => HC
                [status] => inactive
                [# per status] => 2582
                [Live] => 0
            )

        [318] => Array
            (
                [Country] => United States
                [provider] => HC
                [status] => active
                [# per status] => 16217
                [Live] => 16217
            )

        [319] => Array
            (
                [Country] => United States
                [provider] => H UK
                [status] => active
                [# per status] => 70
                [Live] => 70
            )

]
```

The end-result that I want is adding a sub-array for each country to hold the total of LIVE field, just like this:

```
 [320] => Array
                (
                    [Country] => United States
                    [provider] => All Providers
                    [status] => active
                    [# per status] => NULL
                    [Total Live] => 7000 # the total per country goes here
                )
```

I know that PHP functions like `array_walk_recursive` could help but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: so you want that 'LIVE' value to hold the sum of all 'LIVE's per country?

Comment: @ArditMeti I whant to add a total row (sub array) for each country to that will hold the total # of LIVE for that country. I'm going to edit my post to clarify this point.

Comment: you don't need a recursive walk. just a loop. `foreach($arr as $id => $child) { $totals[$child['Country']] += $child['Total Live']; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop your array and build a temporary result with Country as the key and adding Live. Then just merge the values with the original array:

```
foreach($array as $sub) {
    if(!isset($result[$sub['Country']])) {
        $result[$sub['Country']] = array('Country' => $sub['Country'],
                                         'Total Live' => $sub['Live'],
                                         'provider' => 'All Providers',
                                         'status' => 'active',
                                         '# per status' => 'NULL');
    } else {
        $result[$sub['Country']]['Total Live'] += $sub['Live'];
    }
}

$array = array_merge($array, array_values($result));
```

Answer (score 0):

First find all the lives per country than create that temporary array how you wish and just push it to your array.

```
$subArrOfLive = [];
foreach($YOUR_ARR as $val){
    $currCountry = $val["Country"];
    $currLive    = $val["Live"];

    if(!isset($subArrOfLive[$currCountry])) {
        $subArrOfLive[$currCountry] = $currLive;
    }else{
        $subArrOfLive[$currCountry] += $currLive;
    }

}

foreach($subArrOfLive as $key => $val){
    $temp = array(
        "Country" => $key,
        "provider" => "All Providers",
        "status" => "active",
        "# per status" => NULL,
        "Total Live" => $val
    );
    $YOUR_ARR[] = $temp ;
}
```

Comment: that's correct It's just that I have been at work for 7 hours :P tired, let me edit that

Comment: Finished the tasks had nothing to do